# Link values in table to (first) column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**I got a table with no header in which the first column is followed by around 50 other columns with some nan-values and some values that appear more than 5 times.**

I would like to let the values from the 2nd to the last column point to the values in the first column.

For example, my dataframe:
|no header|x|x|x|x|x|
|-|-|-|-|-|-|
|1|NaN|2|2|4|6|
|2|3|3|Nan|7|7|
|3|1|1|9|5|5|

Values don't appear in more than one row, but they may appear more than once in the same row.

Makes:
|value|linked to|
|-----|---------|
|1|3|
|2|1|
|3|2|
|4|1|
|5|3|
|6|1|
|7|2|
|8|NaN|
|9|3|

```
df.values.tolist()
```

Results in a list within a list, not skipping the first column.

Comment: Gerald, can you post some real code to (partially) reproduce your source dataframe -- and if possible, the desired (partial) output?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some quick and dirty code to help myself.

```
df_list = frame1.values.tolist()

z=[]
for x in df_list:
    z.append(set(x))

q=[]
for b in z:
    q.append({x for x in b if x==x})

r=[]
for w in q:
    r.append(list(w))

dict_values = { i+1 : r[i] for i in range(0, len(r) ) }
dict2= {}
for keys,values in dict_values.items():
    for i in values:
        dict2[i]=keys
final = pd.DataFrame(dict2.items())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).